# Correct list type for checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I need my GET Create action method to return two lists to be passed to the view. One is a dropdown list so SelectList type is fine. However, the other is to be displayed as checkboxes. Can anybody advise the correct/best list type to use?

```
    //
    // GET: /Change/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.StaffID = new SelectList(db.Staff, "StaffID", "Fullname")
        ViewBag.BusinessAreas = new *?* (db.BusinessArea, "BusinessArea", "BuinessAreaName");

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom class with all the property you want and use it List list = new List 
Iterate in View to get all the data. Even you can create HTML Helper class and generate the same and use in your view

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the following ways:
1.use [MultiSelectList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.multiselectlist%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). Then you will have to use a jquery to inject checkboxes into your select list, or use a 3rd party control, because I believe MVC3 doesn't have anything built-in with checkboxes.
2. Create a loop in your view and inside your loop create [checkboxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.checkbox%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) for each item. (This is a little bit more work).

Also, please try to avoid using `ViewBag` when possible. Strongly-typed `ViewModels` are much nicer and give you better maintainability and many other advantages over a `ViewBag`.

Comment: Thanks RAS. I don't need checkboxes within a select list. I just need to display checkboxes from a list. I need a list type that accepts 3 arguments - as SelectList does. Thanks again.